# aura.redirect not working with LWC

Tags: community, lightning-web-components

I'm developing a Community and I have a custom Login Aura controller. To log in the user I use the standard `Site.login()` method that returns a `pageReference`, that then is passed to `aura.redirect()`

**Login Controller:**

```
ApexPages.PageReference lgn = Site.login(username, password, startUrl);
if(!Test.isRunningTest())aura.redirect(lgn);
```

`aura.redirect()` won't navigate to Home and it doesn't throw an error either.

---

I've also tried to navigate to Home using `NavigationMixin.Navigate` but it doesn't work either.

I send a response from my controller to my LWC and there in the component I try to navigate from the login page to Home using the following code, but it just won't work

**LWC:**

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type : 'standard__namedPage',
        attributes : {
            pageName : 'home'
        },
});
```

Any ideas on how to log in the user and then take the user from the community login page to Home using LWC?

Comment: Try wrapping your login lwc component in a standard Aura one... then all your UI can be lwc, but hopefully the call to the back end will go through the standard Aura framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well after doing some research I found out that apparently and according to [René Winkelmeyer](https://github.com/muenzpraeger) (Salesforce Principal Developer Evangelist) in this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/issues/86):

> lightning-navigation is currently not a supported experience for
>   Communities.

Comment: I would say that lightning-navigation partially works, it allows to route pages but when you used for authentication it does not work. You can try @Rui Viera solution, that one worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

In Summer '19, Salesforce enhanced the support of lightning-navigation in Community with comm__namedPage (instead of standard__namedPage), pageReferences and state.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_lwc_modules.htm

```
export default class myClass extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
 //...

 goToFAQCategoryMesInstallations() {
  this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
   type: 'comm__namedPage',
   attributes: {
    pageName: 'faq',
   },
   state: {
    'category': 'Mes_installations'
   }
  });
 }
}
```

this will redirect you to 'yourCommunity'/s/faq?category=Mes_installations

Comment: That's absolutely correct, thanks for this.

Comment: hi @Olivier, I tried to use this code, but unfortunately if I call it from login page it redirects to 'mycommunity'/s/login/faq and not to 'mycommunity'/s/faq :( The same for "home" parameter, it redirects to login page, not the home. Any ideas for this?

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution (workaround) for this, you can return the url of the PageReference retrieved from Site.login(), then you'll just need to window.open(url, '_self') in the Component's js. 
As for the PageReference itself it is not a valid type to be returned by AuraEnabled methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass startUrl with portal name where you want to redirect. Like if portal url is 
https://****-****.cs77.force.com/customerportal then you can pass **/customerportal/s** in starturl. This will redirect you to home page after validation.

```
if(site.isValidUsername(username)){
   //startUrl -- put portal name in this variable 
   ApexPages.PageReference lgn = Site.login(username, password, startUrl);
   aura.redirect(lgn);
   return null;                
 }
```